# flask 500 Internal server error

Tags: python, web, flask

I've decided to introduce with flask. I started with HelloWorld-page:

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


app.run()
```

index.html (in the same directory with main.py):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open 127.0.0.1:5000, I get

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Help, please

Comment: What error is the flask application outputting?

Answer (score 1):

Make a directory named `templates` and move `index.html` there. That's where Flask looks for template files.